# Why don't Framer Motion pages load after using the menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm using framer-motion with react to make transitions between my pages, but I have an issue with one transition.

When I'm in the homepage, scroll a bit and click on the menu to go to other page, the next page is empty. In fact by looking in the inspector I can see that the previous page (home) is still in the DOM (+ the new one) and did not exit.

video of the bug : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/11523168

Here's my home component :

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import FirstSection from './FirstSection/FirstSection';
import StickyNav from './FirstSection/StickyNav/StickyNav';
import SndSection from "../sections/Content2/SndSection.js"
import './Home.css';
import LeftOne from "../sections/FirstSection/LeftOne.js";
import ThirdSection from './Content3/ThirdSection';
import { slideContext } from '../../App';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
export default function Home() {
  const context = useContext(slideContext);
    const [scroll, setScroll] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = event => {
          setScroll(window.scrollY);
        };
    
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
      }, []);
  return (
    <motion.div 
    id={context.end ? "end-transition" : ""} 
    className='home'
    initial={{width:0, opacity:0}}
    animate={{width:'100%', opacity:1}}
    exit={{x:window.innerWidth, transition:{duration: 0.3}, opacity:0}}
    >
        {scroll >= 100 ? <StickyNav /> : ""}
        <div id="page">
          <LeftOne element='v1'/>
          <div id="ctn">
            <FirstSection />
            <SndSection />
            <ThirdSection />
          </div>
        </div>
    </motion.div>
  )
}
```

App.js :

```js
 return (
    <HashRouter>
    <slideContext.Provider value={{end, setEnd, endInscr, setEndInscr, number, setNumber}}>
      <div className="App">
        <AnimatedRoutes />
      </div>
    </slideContext.Provider>
    </HashRouter>
  );
```

AnimatedRoutes :

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Routes, Route, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import AboutUs from './AboutUs/AboutUs';
import Error from './Error';
import Inscription from './Inscription/Inscription';
import Thanks from './Inscription/Thanks';
import Privacy from './Privacy/Privacy';
import Home from './sections/Home';
import Terms from './Terms&Conditions/Terms';

import {AnimatePresence} from 'framer-motion';
export default function AnimatedRoutes() {
    const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
        <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/register' element = {<Inscription />} />
            <Route path='/thanks-registration' element ={<Thanks />} />
            <Route path='/aboutUs' element={<AboutUs />}/>
            <Route path='/termsAndConditions' element={<Terms />} />
            <Route path="/privacy" element={<Privacy />}/>
            <Route path="/error" element={<Error />} />
        </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}
```